# keyboard hides textfield for different orientation in ipad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

In my iPad application, I have few `textView` and `textField's`. When I click on `textField`, the keyboard covers the `textField`. So I am implementing the below code to move the textview up. But on rotation to `portraitUpsideDown` its not working fine. It slides the screen down in opposite direction. So how do I solve this problem??

```
-(void) animateTextField: (UITextView *) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    int txtPosition = (textField.frame.origin.y - 540);
    const int movementDistance = (txtPosition < 0 ? 0 : txtPosition); // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
}

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextView *)theTextField
{
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: oopss....just now i checked out your question again..Its for ipad...All orientations are accepted...Sorry to gave u wrong info...

Comment: @DineshRaja.MaG  then how do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your method like this.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Try this. I don't know exactly. But I am trying to help you. May be `x` and `y` coordinate cannot be changed in any orientation. so try this.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
  {
     if(interfaceOrientation=UIInterfaceOrienationPotraitUpsideDown){
          //Declare txtPos globally...
          txtPos=(textField.frame.origin.y + 540);
      }
     if(interfaceOrientation=UIInterfaceOrienationPotrait)
      {
          txtPos=(textField.frame.origin.y - 540);
      }
    return(YES);
  }
```

in animate method.
assign `textPos` to `txtPosition` variable..

Comment: ya its same like above..But on rotation to portraitUpsidedDown its not working.instead of moving up its moving down.It just works fine only for Portrait view not for portraitUpSideDown.

Comment: except your keyboard,is everything else changing its orientation to upsideDown????

Comment: ya everyth else is changing in upsideDown instead of moving screen up its moving down and its hiding the textview..its doing reverse what it was doing in portrait

Comment: you added iboutlet for textfield na...so you can use it for any variable anywhere in your code..only you have to do is declare "txtPos" in your interface file as integer....thats all...

Comment: in your animate method just add this "int txtPosition=txtPos"..instead of "txtPosition=(textField.frame.origin.y - 540)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6541/discussion-between-dineshraja-mag-and-crazy2431)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for iPhone, but it considers both orientations.

You can adapt a bit and voilá:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html

Answer (score 0):

Crazy,

Just add another function:

```
- (void) animateTextView: (UITextView*) textView up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = 80; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Then call it like:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self animateTextView: textView up: YES];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self animateTextView: textView up: NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use keyboard will show and will hide notification to capture keyboard event and adjust your view accordingly.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame);
    CGFloat animationDuration = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    UIViewAnimationOptions animationOption = animationCurve << 16;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 options:animationOption animations:^{
        // adjust height using keyboardHeight
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame);
    CGFloat animationDuration = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    UIViewAnimationOptions animationOption = animationCurve << 16;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0 options:animationOption animations:^{
        // adjust height using keyboardHeight
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

This blog post explains this in detail

http://charlie.cu.cc/2015/10/solution-to-the-ios-software-keyboard-cover-part-of-the-ui/