# keyboard hides textfield in not working with differnt orientation in ipad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using below code to move the textField up when i click on the textfield so that the keyboard should not cover on the textfield.It works fine with the portrait View in ipad.

But when i rotate it to PortraitUpsideDown  it doesnt work.instead of textField moving up its moving down.its performing opposite what it was performing in the portrait orientation.I tried all ways but its not working.plz suggest me how to solve this problem.

This application i am using for ipad.

```
-(void) animateTextField: (UITextView *) textField up: (BOOL) up
{

    int txtPosition = (textField.frame.origin.y - 540);
    const int movementDistance = (txtPosition < 0 ? 0 : txtPosition); // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}


-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField

{

    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];

}

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textField

{

    [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextView *)theTextField 

{

  [theTextField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784316/keyboard-hides-textfield-in-different-orientation-in-ipad

Answer (score 0):

Check the orientation first and then move up/down by using

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)// move down 
else //move up
```

Comment: As you are already setting values for moving down. Use same concept.